# Ubuntu Unity annoying wrapping applications

Tags: virtual-desktop, ubuntu-unity

I have problems with Unity wrapping of application windows that have offscreen bytes.

In the example image, the dotted gray line represents the virtual desktops, and the purpled line reprents a window. If this window have a part off the screen, its wrapped in the other desktop.

[image]

It's also annoying because it also break the tab-cycle of one desktop. E.g: In the example image, desktop 1 the window from desktop 2 is added to the TAB list of applications.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @kpozin, i didn't found a solution for this. I just test today (Ubutnu 13.08) and already happens.